# R create a row graph

Tags: r, graph

I've got a question regarding a graph made from rows.

## Data

```
testdata = structure(c(38, 38, 38, 38, 33, 32, 33, 31, 25, 26, 25, 23, 10, 
                 9, 9, 8, 5, 4, 3, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0), .Dim = c(4L, 6L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, c("V1", "V2", "V3", "V4", "V5", "V6")))
```

## Output

```
     V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6
[1,] 38 33 25 10  5  0
[2,] 38 32 26  9  4  0
[3,] 38 33 25  9  3  0
[4,] 38 31 23  8  5  0
```

This matrix contains 4 samples from 6 different time ticks(V1-V6).
I basically want a scatterplot showing 4 different lines with their value on the Y-axis and on the X-axis the 6 "time ticks". For this I just want the dots and the "average line" of the dots and trust bands. I've done this before but I somehow can't manage it with each sample on a different row.

Comment: Please share what you already tried so far.

Comment: Can you show an example? I am a little... confused.

Comment: Do you mean something like `matplot(testdata, t="l", lty = 1)`?

Comment: Maybe `plot(1:ncol(testdata),ty="n",ylim=range(testdata)*c(0.9,1.1));apply(testdata,1,lines)`?

Comment: In excel the graph would look something like: http://i.imgur.com/osTV74T.png

Comment: @nico rather something like `matplot(t(testdata), t="l", lty = 1, pch=c(19, 15, 17, 4))`

Comment: @nicola Error in plot.new() : figure margins too large

Comment: @nico Error in plot.new() : figure margins too large

Comment: I guess you have `NA` in your data. Try `plot(1:ncol(testdata),ty="n",ylim=range(testdata,na.rm=TRUE)*c(0.9,1.1))`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To get something like the excel plot example you gave, you can do:

```
matplot(t(testdata), t="b", pch=c(18, 15, 17, 4), lty=1, col=c("blue", "red", "green", "purple"), lwd=2)
```

[image]

Following @nico advice, you can also use `type="o"` if you want continuous lines:

```
matplot(t(testdata), t="o", pch=c(18, 15, 17, 4), lty=1, col=c("blue", "red", "green", "purple"), lwd=2)
```

[image]

Comment: A very minor thing: using `type = "o"` gives nicer looking plots as it does not break the line :)

Comment: @nico thanks for the tip! :-) I've edited my answer to add the option

Answer (score 4):

Another option in the base plotting system:

```
ndat<-as.data.frame(testdata)

plot(t(ndat[1,]), type="l", col="red", lwd=2, xlab="x-axis", ylab="values")
lines(t(ndat[2,]), type="l", col="yellow", lwd=2)
lines(t(ndat[3,]), type="l", col="green", lwd=2)
lines(t(ndat[4,]), type="l", col="blue", lwd=2)
```

[image]

Comment: `matplot` is the base plotting system.

Comment: that is why I said "another" ... ;-)

Comment: You could also wrap the various `lines` call into an `apply` one-liner